# what does \ mean in NumPy Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and I am working with numpy in python. I am stuck here and cannot understand what does this sign "/" does here. can anybody please help.

```
random_mutation_boolean = \
random_mutation_array <= mutation_probability

population[random_mutation_boolean] = \
np.logical_not(population[random_mutation_boolean])
```

Comment: it is just python for linebreak, since the line is longer than 80char.

Comment: it does nothing

Comment: The line continuation character is a backslash (“\”).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python line continuation character lets you continue a line of code on a new line in your program. The line continuation character cannot be followed by any value. If you specify a character or statement after a line continuation character, you encounter the “SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character” error.

[above taken from](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-syntaxerror-unexpected-character-after-line-continuation-character/#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20line%20continuation%20character%20lets%20you%20continue,%E2%80%9CSyntaxError%3A%20unexpected%20character%20after%20line%20continuation%20character%E2%80%9D%20error.)

Comment: The line continuation character is a backslash (“\”).